# when use inject (@EJB) or lookup for referencing an ejb?

Tags: jsf, ejb

i have a @Singleton Bean that i want to use in another @stateless Bean, is that correct or doable? and can i reference the stateless bean using @EJB? in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632136/1026897) i read that i can't. should i use only lookup? why?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answer is talking about injecting a `@Stateful` in a `@Stateless` which is indeed an extremely bad idea. But you've there just a `@Singleton` and you should be able to inject it without any trouble in any kind of EJB (as long as it is *really* been designed as such that it indeed deserves a `@Singleton`), there's only one unique instance of the `@Singleton` anyway.

See also this related answer: [access existing instance stateful inside stateless, java ee 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384368/access-existing-instance-stateful-inside-stateless-java-ee-6/9384670#9384670).

Comment: i use the @Singleton bean to manage a queue for mail sending.
 thanks @BalusC!